# Disable Ctrl+Enter

Tags: emacs, elpy

I am using python with elpy mode which work fine, however I am really annoyed by the default which runs executes the command under the cursor whenever I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> since I keep pressing it accidentally.
How do I disable this behavior? I tried

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-return>") nil)
```

but that does not seem to have an effect. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably not set in the global key map, but in the major mode's map or some minor mode's map.  In a buffer with the key bound, do `C-h k C-<return>` to see the binding; it should show the key map that it's in.  Then use `define-key` to change it.  E.g. if `foo-mode-map` contains the binding, do

```
(define-key foo-mode-map (kbd "C-<return>") nil)
```

You will probably want to add that code to either a hook or wrap it in `with-eval-after-load`, so `foo-mode-map` is defined when it runs.

Comment: You can find out what mode map the key belongs to by pressing `C-h k C-Ret`.